# How do I depend on a specific version of a homebrew formula

Tags: homebrew

I'm having a conflict with a formula and a particular version of Boost. Ideally, since this is really just a build conflict (it's not using a Boost shared library), I'd like to automatically use a specific version when building. I doubt this is possible, so I'd really just be happy with it as a conflict or as dependency, but I can't find documentation for that. What I found is the generic dependency example:

```
class Foo < Formula
  depends_on "boost" => "with-icu"
end
```

Is this even something I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew is still improving their support for depending on old versions of a library, with some planned improvements in [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/567). In the meantime, you can use the [homebrew/versions tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions), which has formulae for boost 1.55 and boost 1.59. To depend on these versioned formulae, you could use the following:

```
depends_on "homebrew/versions/boost155"
```

or

```
depends_on "homebrew/versions/boost159"
```

EDIT:

You mentioned lack of documentation about conflicts. There is a [conflicts_with](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=conflicts) keyword, but that is more about conflicts with being installed side-by-side. There's also a [fails_with](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=fails_with) keyword, but that is related to specific versions of compilers. I think using `depends_on` with a formula from `homebrew/versions` will work best for you.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned lack of documentation about conflicts. There is a [conflicts_with](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=conflicts) keyword, but that is more about conflicts with being installed side-by-side. There's also a [fails_with](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=fails_with) keyword, but that is related to specific versions of compilers. I think the answer has the best approach for you.